# How to echo value from a column using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and having problems with printing values from database.

This is my code:

```
<?
$level = $db->Query("SELECT `level` FROM users WHERE `id` = '" . $data['id'] . "'");
$r2 = mysql_fetch_object($level);
?>
```

And this is what it looks like when I try to print it:

```
<?php
echo $r2;
?>
```

And when I try to echo it it doesn't print the value from level but it only loads half of the page.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Although we cannot see what kind of object `$db` is, I'm guessing it is a MySQLi connection object. The return value of `query()` call is a result resource, from which you must fetch rows.

Comment: [This is probably what you have](http://us1.php.net/mysqli_query), but it may be something else. We cannot say without seeing first how `$db` was instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

$level is a mysql result resource. Try adding the following

```
while ($row = $level->fetch_row()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is returning a result resource. You need to use that with a fetch function of some kind to retrieve the actual data. If you're using MySQLi, then you can use [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row) or similar.

Comment: I don't know if I understood what to do but I just tried:

$r2 = mysql_fetch_object($level);

and then echo $r2; but the page only loads half of the website now.

Comment: @user2989236: Please edit the question and include more code (not the whole code, just include the relevant part).

Comment: I tried to update the code, that is pretty much all I have.

Comment: @user2989236: Did you read the documentation for `mysql_fetch_assoc` or any other MySQL functions, yet? If not, that might be a good start.